# Cannot start config manager on intramaps roam

Tags: qgis, intramaps-roam

I get the following error when trying to start Intramaps roam on a windows 7 Motion tablet.

Errors Occurred: See the logfile 'C:\Intramaps Roam\ Roam Config Manager.exe.log' for details

The logfile is shown below.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File “__main__py”, line 23, in <module>
  File “configmanager\ui\configmanagerdialog.pyc”, line 12, in <module>
ImportError: No module named events
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File “__main__py”, line 23, in <module>
  File “configmanager\ui\configmanagerdialog.pyc”, line 12, in <module>
ImportError: No module named events
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File “__main__py”, line 23, in <module>
  File “configmanager\ui\configmanagerdialog.pyc”, line 12, in <module>
ImportError: No module named events`
```

It has worked in the past on the same tablet, until I upgraded the software version. I have since downgraded but the error still appears.

I have attempted installing ROAM and QGIS on another tablet but I still get the same error.

I have also attempted re-installs and reboots to no avail. I have also edited the roam.config file to ensure the path is correct for QGIS to 'C:/Program Files/QGIS Essen/bin/qgis.bat'.

Comment: The error has gone since I uninstalled everything and started with a clean slate. Upon further investigation, I found that the problem lay with spatialite layers used in the project. They had autoincrementing primary keys, and using ROAM to edit those features (after saving) caused further errors to appear. However, when I used shapefiles ROAM performed well.

Comment: Unfortunately, I would prefer to use spatialite so that I can generate autoincrementing primary keys that can be used in 1:M joins when capturing data.